# Stuck in converting one complex formula into VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7

Below is the formula:-

`=DROP(REDUCE("",A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),LAMBDA(x,y,LET(z,BYROW(C2:C5,LAMBDA(v,SUM(N(v=x)))),VSTACK(x,TAKE(TOCOL(IFS((D2:D5+z)=MIN((D2:D5+z)),C2:C5),2),1))))),1)`

Explanation of formula:-

I have one column in excel "Variants" in sheet1 which contain no. of parts in A column. These parts are remaining parts which are left to allocate to analyst.

[image]

In the same sheet I have two columns "Analyst" ,"count"(at C and D). Analyst contain analyst name or my team name and count contain number of different parts they have already allocated. like below

[image]

Now I want to allocate remaining parts which is in Variant column to my analyst in such a manner that there count will be equal. below is output after putting above formula.

[image]

See this formula allocate only one part to jawed  because it has already count 2 and remaining analyst got 3 parts to match equal count.

Now the problem with this formula is taking lot of time as I need to add into VBA code as well as it hang excel too.

I tried below VBA code to achieve the same but not getting like above formula. it allocate analyst only at the last two variants.

```
Sub AllocateAnalysts()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim variantsCount As Long
    Dim analystCounts() As Long
    Dim minCountIndex As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your actual sheet name
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column B
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Initialize analystCounts array
    ReDim analystCounts(1 To lastRow)
    
    ' Loop through the data to count analyst occurrences
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        analystCounts(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.Range("D2:D" & lastRow), ws.Cells(i, 4))
    Next i
    
    ' Loop through the data to allocate analysts to variants
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        variantsCount = ws.Cells(i, 5)
        For j = 1 To variantsCount
            ' Find the index of the analyst with the minimum count
            minCountIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(analystCounts), analystCounts, 0)
            
            ' Assign the analyst to the Allocation column
            ws.Cells(minCountIndex, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
            
            ' Increment the count for the assigned analyst
            analystCounts(minCountIndex) = analystCounts(minCountIndex) + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Can some one please help me out.

Comment: I would consider setting this up using the Solver, but it will depend on how many parts / people etc

Comment: It would be helpful if you add a markdown table with your data to check the code. E.g. `ws.Cells(i, 5)` refers to column E. What is in column E?

Comment: | abc | Variants | Allocation | analyst  | count |
|-----|----------|------------|-------|-------|
| abc | hello    | moti       | jawed | 2     |
| abc | hello    | sohan      | rohan | 1     |
| abc | hello    | vicky      | moti  | 0     |
| abc | hello    | rohan      | sohan | 0     |
| abc | hello    | moti       | vicky | 0     |
| abc | hello    | sohan      |       |       |
| abc | hello    | vicky      |       |       |

when i was writing VBA I added one more extra column abc at A

Comment: Pls. edit it in your post with clicking Edit under the tags. From comments it cannot be copied to a spreadsheet.

Comment: The loop with the `j` variable seems weird. You iterate two times (in the first row for jawed) , overwrite the analyst and increase `count` also two times for the same part.

Comment: VBA code is Editable. I don't get it j loop.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the reason of switching to vba if you have a working solution already?

Why not run the formula and paste as values using vba (start with `screenupdating = False`, end with `screenupdating = True`)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Its working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I did this as an example:

[image]

There is a limit to how many cells the Solver works with, Frontline offers a package for that.

Comment: Hi Thanks, But this Variant and analyst count will change many times  Some time it will be 2 or some time it will be 15 or 30. Variant anb Analyst will be paste by another VBA.